# onchange Jquery not working when changing value with a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use sth like onchange but with no results.

i've been searching for a while but i didn't find.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

<div id="button"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $("#button").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#myInput").val("new value");
    });

    $("#myInput").on('change keyup paste blur oncut propertychange', function()
    {
        //my code
    });
</script>
```

I can't find a event where a JQ action is recognized like a changing in my input...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$("#myInput").val("new value").change();` There is no events for that. Trigger the change manually.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put these js code part into the $(document).ready(function(){
});
I think because these js is not loaded when the webpage is completed loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#myInput").val("new value");
    });

    $("#myInput").on('change keyup paste blur oncut propertychange', function()
    {
        console.log('event detected');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<div id="button"></div>
</body>
</html>
```